# Issue changing database JSON Array data in a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a TableView controller that is populated from JSON Array the TableView Controller also has a `BarButtonItem` called `doneButton`.

The idea is to select a few rows in the tableView controller and press the `doneButton`. This should change the `status` of all the selected rows to `Done`.

**The JSON array looks like the following example:**

```
[
    {
        "customer": "John",
        "status": "Working",
    },
    {
        "customer": "James",
        "status": "Working",
    },
    {
        "customer": "Jamie",
        "status": "Working",
    }
]
```

The structure is defined as: `var structure = [Structure]()`

```
import UIKit

struct Structure: Codable {
    let customer: String
    let status: String
}
```

**The TableView Delegate code so far:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if isFiltering() {
        return pickup.count
    }
    print(structure.count)
    return structure.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "testingCell", for: indexPath)


    let portfolio: Structure
    portfolio = structure[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = portfolio.customer
    return cell

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none

}
```

After selecting a few customer names followed by selecting `doneButton` the status (which is not presented in the tableView) should change to `Done`

The change should also reflect the mysql database the `JSON` is pulling from, how can this be done.

Answer (score 0):

You should add one more property in Structure (struct) that will save the selection status of the row. So next time if tableview  will be reloaded  it will so selected status of the row.

```
struct Structure: Codable {
    let customer: String
    let status: String
    var isSelected: Bool
}
```

In tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) in method
add

```
if portfolio.isSelected == true {
   cell.accessoryType = . checkmark
} else {
   cell.accessoryType = .done
}
```

Also, change the status value of isSelected in tabelview didSelectRowAt and didDeselectRowAt.

And if you want to save this selection in the database then you have to create one more column in your table and save the selected value in the database.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Saving the changes to the database is where I am having issues. After selecting the `doneButton` all the db records represented by the tableView rows should also update. Any ideas of how I can use CoreData to accomplish this?

Comment: You see what mean?